# WPF Using GridSplitter outside of a grid Jumping re-size issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using a `GridSplitter` outside of a grid in a `DockPanel` to try and control the width of my docked items. I'm using it because of it has all the necessary drag events built in. The issue i'm having is that since when i re-size my docked item, the `GridSplitter` is moving to accommodate the width, thus throwing the Splitters Horrizontal Change value out.

Gif of the result:

[image]

You can also see by the console output of the `HorrizontalChange` value on the splitters DragDelta event exactly whats happening to the internal value.

[image]

The code i'm using for this can be found below:

Window.xaml.cs:

```
        private double _rightContainerWidthBeforeDrag;

        private void RightGridSplitter_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Change: " + e.HorizontalChange);
            DockContainerRight.Width = _rightContainerWidthBeforeDrag + e.HorizontalChange * -1;
        }

        private void RightGridSplitter_DragStarted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragStartedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Started: " + DockContainerRight.ActualWidth);
            _rightContainerWidthBeforeDrag = DockContainerRight.ActualWidth;
        }

        private void RightGridSplitter_DragCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            _rightContainerWidthBeforeDrag = DockContainerRight.ActualWidth;
        }
```

Window.xaml

```
    <DockPanel>
        <controls:DockContainer x:Name="DockContainerLeft" DockPosition="Left" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
        <controls:DockContainer x:Name="DockContainerRight" DockPosition="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
        <controls:DockContainer x:Name="DockContainerBottom" DockPosition="Bottom" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>

        <GridSplitter Name="RightGridSplitter" DockPanel.Dock="Right" ResizeDirection="Columns" Width="3" Height="Auto" Margin="0"
            DragDelta="RightGridSplitter_DragDelta"
            DragStarted="RightGridSplitter_DragStarted"
            DragCompleted="RightGridSplitter_DragCompleted"/>
    </DockPanel>
```

I think i must be using the information on the events wrong, or have a floor in my maths. What can i do to fix this? Or alternatively is there a better way for me to do this that wont encounter the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI(DockContainerRight.Width) update in Window.xaml.cs causes the problem. You can try to wrap the GridSplitter and DockContainerRight in a grid.

```
<DockPanel>
            <controls:DockContainer  x:Name="DockContainerBottom"  Height="50" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <controls:DockContainer x:Name="DockContainerLeft" Grid.Column="0"  />
                <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="3"  Margin="0"/>
                <controls:DockContainer x:Name="DockContainerRight" Grid.Column="2"  />

            </Grid>
        </DockPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but thats causing some crazy resize behavior with my main page on the left, and it's not resizing the DockContainer at all.

Comment: Answer Updated. Try to wrap DockContainerLeft, DockContainerRight and GridSplitter into the grid.

Comment: Thanks ill give it a go, thinking about it i'm not really using the DockPanel for whats its meant for, so splitting it up in a grid like you've suggested is probably a better way of doing it anyway.